# Google app engine - is it possible to create two web clients that will use the same datastore?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, web

I created an application using Google app engine
I have two clients at the moment - one for android and another one for web application
and I want to add a mobile web application as well that will use the same datastore
I can't deploy the mobile web application because it will overwrite the web application that I already have

What do I need to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Datastore is effectively partitioned by application. If you're operating on the same data, does anything prevent merging applications?

Answer (score 0):

When you say two clients, do you mean two GAE apps?

The easiest (but probably not ideal) way to deal with it is to upload them as separate versions of the same app.  GAE allows you to access different versions of the same app via different urls.  You can then point your android app and the mobile web app at the appropriate urls.

Generally the better way to do it would be to design your mobile app and web app to use the same APIs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for App Engine Modules, which provide multiple front ends (e.g. web apps, RESTful APIs, etc.) to the same underlying stateful services such as the datastore, memcache, and task queues.  Each module can have its own set of versions, its own scaling configuration, and may be deployed independently of the others.

Java docs are [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/).

Python docs are [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/).